# Sorting a Django QuerySet by a property (not a field) of the Model

Tags: python, django-models, django-templates

### Some code and my goal

My (simplified) model:

```
class Stop(models.Model):
    EXPRESS_STOP = 0
    LOCAL_STOP   = 1

    STOP_TYPES = (
        (EXPRESS_STOP, 'Express stop'),
        (LOCAL_STOP, 'Local stop'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STOP_TYPES)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def _get_cost(self):
        if self.price == 0:
            return 0
        elif self.type == self.EXPRESS_STOP:
            return self.price / 2
        elif self.type == self.LOCAL_STOP:
            return self.price * 2
        else:
            return self.price    
    cost = property(_get_cost)
```

**My Goal**: I want to sort by the `cost` property. I tried two approaches.

### Using order_by QuerySet API

```
Stops.objects.order_by('cost')
```

That yielded the following template error:

```
Caught FieldError while rendering: Cannot resolve keyword 'cost' into field.
```

### Using dictsort template filter

```
{% with deal_items|dictsort:"cost_estimate" as items_sorted_by_price %}
```

Received the following template error:

```
Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [cost] in u'Union Square'
```

### So...

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`QuerySet.extra()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.extra) along with `CASE ... END` to define a new field, and sort on that.

```
Stops.objects.extra(select={'cost': 'CASE WHEN price=0 THEN 0 '
  'WHEN type=:EXPRESS_STOP THEN price/2 WHEN type=:LOCAL_STOP THEN price*2'},
  order_by=['cost'])
```

That, or cast the `QuerySet` returned from the rest to a list, then use `L.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('cost'))` on it.

Comment: I like your 2nd method. However, how would I sort by `cost` if it is a property of a related model? Example: In `Stop` model we have `pricing = models.ForeignKey(Pricing)` and `cost` is a property of `Pricing`.

Comment: `key=lambda x: x.pricing.cost`