# Django order_by a property

Tags: django, django-models

I'm faced with a problem wherein I'm trying to create a QuerySet with the results ordered not by a field on a model, but instead ordered by the result of a value returned by a method on the model.

To wit:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

someAttributes = models.TextField(blank=True)

@property
def calculate_rating(self):
<do some calculation and return integer>
```

Given that, how can I construct a QuerySet that orders the results by the value for each instance as returned by calculate_rating()?

In trying to simply use order_by(), I get an error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'average_rating' into field.

Can anybody provide some ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a Django QuerySet by a property (not a field) of the Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175749/sorting-a-django-queryset-by-a-property-not-a-field-of-the-model)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to do this. One thing you can do is to create a separate database field for that model and save the calculated rating in it. You can probably override the save method of the model and do the calculations there, after that you can only refer to the value.

You can also sort the returned `QuerySet` using [`Python sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted). Take into account that the sorting approach using the built-in sorted function increases a lot the computational complexity and it's not a good idea to use such code in production.

For more information you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/981802/1869597

Answer (score 22):

`order_by` is for database stuff. Try to use `sorted` instead:

```
sorted(MyModel.objects.all(),  key=lambda m: m.calculate_rating)
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve what you want, is by using the `Case` and `When` statements. This allows you to keep the final result in `QuerySet` instead of list ;)

```
ratings_tuples = [(r.id, r.calc_rating) for r in MyModel.objects.all()]  
ratings_list = sorted(ratings_tuples, key = lambda x: x[1])  # Sort by second tuple elem
```

So here is our sorted list `ratings_list` that holds IDs and ratings of the elements in a sorted way

```
pk_list = [idx for idx, rating in ratings_list]  
from django.db.models import Case, When
preserved = Case(*[When(pk=pk, then=pos) for pos, pk in enumerate(pk_list)])  
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list).order_by(preserved)
```

Now, using `Case` and `When` statements, we are able to do the queryset sorting itself by the IDs from the list we already have. ([Django Docs for details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)).
Had a similar situation and needed a solution. So found some details on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/37648265/4271452, it works.

Comment: Nice! It's less clear what is going on here than with `sorted` to be sure, but there are many cases where it is necessary to keep the result as a queryset.