# Django 1.6: How to order a query set by a computed DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, sql-order-by, django-queryset, calculated-field

I have a **project** model having a `DateTimeField` and duration `PositiveIntegerField` fields.

The model also has a function **days_left** implementing relatively involved logic to compute the number of days left till expiry. The function returns an integer.

I want to preform a simple queryset ordering by the value returned by this function.

```
    Project.objects.all().order_by('days_left')
```

However I keep getting an exception to the effect that **days_left** is not a field.

Is there any efficient way to do this in native SQL (maybe through views, etc..) and bypass the queryset or does there exist a django solution for such cases?

The whole code:

```
import datetime as nsdt
from django.db import models 
from django.utils import timezone

class Project(models.Model):
    name                        = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    publish_date                = models.DateTimeField()
    duration_days               = models.PositiveIntegerField() 

    def days_left(self):
        t1 = timezone.now()
        t2 = self.publish_date + nsdt.timedelta(days=self.duration_days)
        return (t2 - t1).days if t2 > t1 else 0


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print Project.objects.all().order_by('days_left')
    # throws excpetion: 
    #    django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'days_left_computed' into field.
```

Answer (score 2):

Since sorting is happening on the database level, you cannot use Django's `order_by` for this. Instead, you can try sorting the objects using `sorted()`.

```
projects = sorted(Project.objects.all(), key=lambda x: x.days_left())
```

**Update:**

Since you have a large number of records, maybe you can use the [Queryset.extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175749/sorting-a-django-queryset-by-a-property-not-a-field-of-the-model)

Another approach you may try is using [django.db.models.F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/).

Example using `F()` (disclaimer: this was not tested)

```
from django.db.models import F

projects = Project.objects.all().order_by((F('publish_date') + nsdt.timedelta(days=F('duration_days'))) - timezone.now())
```

Comment: This solution is OK but I have millions of records.

Comment: Updated the answer and added few possible approach