# Order queryset by a method in django

Tags: python, django, methods, sql-order-by, django-queryset

I am trying to order QuerySet by a method defined in my class

```
Class EgzampleClass(models.Model):
    somefield =  models.ForeignKey(User)
    otherfield = models.CharField()

    @property
    def mymethod(self):
        countsth=1
        return countsth
```

I would like to do a thing like this

```
EgzampleClass.objects.all().order_by('mymethod')
```

Does anyone have an idea how can I do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a Django QuerySet by a property (not a field) of the Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175749/sorting-a-django-queryset-by-a-property-not-a-field-of-the-model)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I was looking for an answer, no idea why I didn't find it, thank you for help :)